# OscpVerifier validating OCSP signers certificate against current date instead of signDate - bug or feature?

Tags: pdf, itext, digital-signature

I am using iTextSharp 5.5.13 in order to sign and validate PDF files. Few days ago I ended up with **exception in OcspVerifier.Verify** which stated **"certificate expired on 20181225...GMT+00:00"**

All PDF files are signed with embeded OCSP response and CLR. Validation was done using signing date and it used to work fine **until the ocsp signers certificate expired**.

Despite the fact that all certificates were valid at the time of signing, the OcspVerifier.Verify started to throw exception which states "cert expired...".

```
if (pkcs7.Ocsp != null)
     ocsps.Add(pkcs7.Ocsp);
PdfOcspVerifier ocspVerifier = new PdfOcspVerifier(null, ocsps);
ocspVerifier.OnlineCheckingAllowed = false;
List<VerificationOK> verification = ocspVerifier.Verify(signCert, issuerCert, signDate.ToUniversalTime());

EXCEPTION: "certificate expired on 20181225...GMT+00:00"
```

It looks like bug to me? Is there any reason why OCSP signer certificate is not verified against signing date?

Class OscpVerifier - original, with line which validate cert against current date:

```
 virtual public void IsValidResponse(BasicOcspResp ocspResp, X509Certificate issuerCert)
{
....
    //check if lifetime of certificate is ok
    responderCert.CheckValidity();
}
```

Modified version of OscpVerifier.cs:

```
// old definition with old functionality
virtual public void IsValidResponse(BasicOcspResp ocspResp, X509Certificate issuerCert)
{
            IsValidResponse(ocspResp, issuerCert, DateTime.UtcNow);
}

// with signDate parameter:
virtual public void IsValidResponse(BasicOcspResp ocspResp, X509Certificate issuerCert, DateTime signDate)
{
...

    //check if lifetime of certificate is ok
    responderCert.CheckValidity(signDate);
    //responderCert.CheckValidity();
}
```

with corresponding method call change fom:

```
virtual public bool Verify(BasicOcspResp ocspResp, X509Certificate signCert, X509Certificate issuerCert, DateTime signDate)
{
...
...     {
            // check if the OCSP response was genuine
            IsValidResponse(ocspResp, issuerCert);
            return true;
        }
...
}
```

to:

```
virtual public bool Verify(BasicOcspResp ocspResp, X509Certificate signCert, X509Certificate issuerCert, DateTime signDate)
{
...
...     {
            // check if the OCSP response was genuine
            IsValidResponse(ocspResp, issuerCert, signDate);
            return true;
        }
...
}
```

I included this variation of the OscpVerifier class directly in the project and it validates now old signatures as expected.

However, I am not sure **if I hit the bug or there is reason why those signatures should be considered as not valid?**

Comment: You mention embedded CRLs and OCSP responses. But are they digitally time stamped? If they are not then, depending on the valuation model used, they have to be validated for the current date and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OCSP signer certificate must be validated at current time except if the OCSP response has been protected with a time stamp, so itext is working properly.

---

Summarizing,  an OCSP response contains (See [RFC6960](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6960) ):

- target certificate and validity interfal
- time when the response was generated
- A digital signature of a CA trusted responder, and its certificate

The criteria for accepting an OCSP response is established in the RFC, but it does not clarify your question, because it does not establish how to validate the response over time.

> 3.2.  Signed Response Acceptance Requirements

> Prior to accepting a signed response for a particular certificate as
> valid, OCSP clients SHALL confirm that:

> 1. The certificate identified in a received response corresponds to the certificate that was identified in the corresponding request;

> 2. The signature on the response is valid;

> 3. The identity of the signer matches the intended recipient of the  request;

> 4. The signer is currently authorized to provide a response for the certificate in question;

> 5. The time at which the status being indicated is known to be correct (thisUpdate) is sufficiently recent;

> 6. When available, the time at or before which newer information will be available about the status of the certificate (nextUpdate) is greater than the current time.

However, it does indicate that the digital signature must be valid (2). In general, for a signature to be considered valid, it must comply with:

- Cryptographic integrity
- Validity of the certificate (expiration and revocation)

An OCSP response with an expired certificate will not meet the second criterion and therefore should be rejected. To extend the period in which a signature is valid, a time stamp must be added on the content. The PAdES standard specifies how

There is also an ETSI guide with the details on how to perform the verification of a PAdES and CAdES signatures, but unfortunately I have not found the link now

Comment: *"a time stamp must be added on the content. The PAdES standard specifies how"* - if the op is working in a context which is not related to ETSI profiles: already the first pdf specification (ISO 32000-1) contained a description of a way to time stamp a signature.

Comment: Thank You. I will provide users with several statuses of signature which is validated. If I want to preserve validity of those signatures, I have to timestamp them before the expiration of any signature in chain?

Comment: Exactly, at the time that the signing certificate, OCSP responses, or CRL expire, the signature will be considered invalid. The time stamp protects everything. The timestamp is usually added during the signature process itself to avoid this problem.